# Working with ASP.NET Razor and HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

I have a list of categories and sub categories which is passing from controller to the view. Now, I want them to be represented in the HTML like following. But, I dont know how can i achieve this by using foreach or table or whatever.

[image]

**EDIT** : Code

```
public ActionResult Electronics()
    {
        var topCategories = pe.Categories.Where(category => category.ParentCategory.CategoryName == "Electronics").ToList();
        //var catsAndSubs = pe.Categories.Include("ParentCategory").Where(c => c.ParentCategory.CategoryName == "Electronics");
        return View(topCategories);
    }
```

*With this view code, I am just able to pull a vertical list.*

`@foreach (var cats in Model)
{
    <li>@cats.CategoryName</li>
    foreach (var subcats in cats.SubCategories)
    {
        <li>@subcats.CategoryName</li>
    }
}`

Comment: @Pankaj.You can do this with DIV's easily

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) There are a few ways to make this

Comment: @Null Using div in a foreach would only yield a vertical list of categories.

Comment: @Frederiek I am just not able to understand how can this be achieved. If I use a table inside a foreach loop, either i can add a row or a column. Similarly with <div> also there is just a vertical list. I want the list to be presented in vertical and horizontal manner

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay You can create this with <div> and CSS easily. Just search some examples on <div> with float. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: @Pankaj, you can do this using div with the help of CSS as Frederik said. But the logic is completely depend upon how you send data to view . How you are sneding data to view. using a single list ??

Comment: @NullPointer I have edited the code in question. I guess people are not understand what i am asking. I know about <div> and CSS but how should i use them in `@foreach` is the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When designing HTML mark-up it is very important to consider [semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML).  What meaning are you trying to convey?  That doesn't look like tabular data to me so please don't put it in tables :P

Based on your wireframe above, the way I would probably structure this is like this:

```
<h1>Category Directory</h1>

<h2><a href="/projectors">Multimedia Projectors</a></h2>

<h2><a href="/audio">Home Audio</a></h2>
<p>
    <a href="/audio/amps">Amplifiers</a>, <a href="/audio/speakers">Speakers</a>
</p>
```

Adjust the hX tags to reflect their position within the document's hierachy. Remember to only ever have ONE h1 per page (or per <acticle>, or <section> if using HTML5).

If instead you wind up turning this into something like a [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples) menu then this is the markup that you would use:

```
<nav id="category_menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/projectors">Multimedia Projectors</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/audio">Home Audio</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/audio/amps">Amplifiers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/audio/speakers">Speakers</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Edit**
Your model is not suitable for creating your desired view, the relationship is bottom-up, but to conveniently construct the view you will want the relationships defined top-down.  You need to start by converting the data model into a view model, such as:

```
class CategoryViewModel
{
    string CategoryName { get;set; }
    IList<CategoryModel> SubCategories { get;set; }
}
```

and to make this:

```
IList<CategoryViewModel> Map(IList<CategoryDataModel> dataModel)
{
   var model = new List<CategoryViewModel>();

   //Select the categories with no parent (these are the root categories)
   var rootDataCategories = dataModel.Where(x => x.ParentCategory == null);

   foreach(var dataCat in rootDataCategories )
   {
       //Select the sub-categories for this root category
       var children = dataModel
           .Where(x => x.ParentCategory != null && x.ParentCategory.Name = cat.Name)
           .Select(y => new CategoryViewModel() { CategoryName = y.CategoryName })
           .ToList();

       var viewCat = new CategoryViewModel()
       {
           CategoryName = dataCat.CategoryName,
           SubCategories = children
       };

       model.Add(viewCat);
   }

   return model;
}
```

Then your view:

```
<h1>Category Directory</h1>

@foreach(var category in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("Category", category)
}
```

Category partial:

```
<h2>@Html.ActionLink(Model.CategoryName, "Detail", new { Model.CategoryName })</h2>

@if(Model.SubCategories.Count> 0)
{
<p>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SubCategories.Count; i++)
    {
        var subCat = Model.SubCategories[i];
        @Html.ActionLink(subCat.CategoryName, "Detail", new { subCat.CategoryName })

        @if(i < Model.SubCategories.Count - 1)
        {
            <text>,</text>
        }
    }
</p>
}
```

Note that my current solution only supports 2 levels of categories (as per your wireframe).  It could however be easily extended to be recursive.

Comment: I am passing a list and need to use that for generating the listings. I just cant figure it out as to how can one generate this using @foreach.

Comment: No need to downvote me on account of your not explaining your problem properly.

Based on your updated question, you're going to need to start by creating a tree-based model from your data model. Your data model has a link back to a parent, whereas to conveniently build a view you will want a category to contain a collection of children.

Comment: I didnt downvoted you any personal reasons. I totally acknowledge your time and effort. It's just that this isn't the answer to my problem and yes may be you are right, I am unable to explain what i really want. No hard feelings , sorry if you felt bad.